# Error HRESULT 0x800A03EC in Excel Charts

Tags: excel, vba

Whenever on opening an excel chart with my macros code, it shows the error `HRESULT 0x800A03EC` Issues.

Comment: What version of excel are you using? Are you using backwards compability sheet?

Comment: Which code generates the error?

Comment: The problem got solved. The error was due to some registry entry. I have repaired Microsoft office16 and it works fine now

Answer (score 0):

The problem got solved. The error was due to some invalid registry entry. I have repaired Microsoft office16 and it works fine now

Comment: Your question is altogether unclear, and your answer is even more mysterious. “I had a problem, and now I’ve solved it” would have been more useful as it would have saved unnecessary time reading so many words.